# Displaying Progress Bar in a Multi-Branch Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a wizard.  One of the requirements is to display where the user is in the workflow (ie: Step 1 of 5).  My problem is at any point the steps remaining could change depending on what the user answers.  Let me highlight with an example.

Q1: What is your name?

Q2: What is your age?

```
(a) 0-18 => User selects a, there are 3 questions remaining
(b) 19-65 => User selects b, there are 4 questions remaining.
(c) 65+ => User select c, there is 1 question remaining.
```

So in Q1, there is no way to know which answer the user is going to pick in Q2.  What would I display to the user in Q1?  Has anyone encountered this before?  If so I would love to hear your opinion.  Please keep in mind that the example is simplified and I have many branches in my workflow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this.. assign weightage  to each step of the wizard assuming for the maximum branches it can have. then if he select a branch which have less branches than maximum then simply Push the progress to the maximum for that branch.

like if my All branches can contribute to a 100%
and each branch can have at most 5 options then set 20% as the maximum for that branch.

Now if user selects something that has no more options then simply push to 20% otherwise only push 4%.(user is not blind he can see that now he has more fields to fill)

*(Actually this was a problem of a Coding competition in my school...)*

Comment: I think for the most part I understand what you are saying.  Can we go through my example?  So in step one, I would display 17% (1 out of 6 if the user picks 19-65 in Q2).  In Q2, I would display 33% (2/6).  In Q3 (if a was selected) - 50% (3/6), if b was selected) - 43% (3/7), if c was selected 75% (3 of 4).  Is my logic correct?  Also, does this mean that you need to keep track of the maximum remaining steps left at every question?

Comment: Thats not exactly what i said.. but yeah want you mentioned is more Correct according to your Scenario (because there are no options in 1st question, just in second one). And i dont think think there is any problem in keeping track of question left... Good luck  ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think, You should display progress completed as 0 % or do not show progress at all as there is no way to know in advance that what is the answer of Q2 while answering Q1.

so when user select Q2 only then show progress

Comment: The problem I have with not displaying any progress is what if a branch occurs at the 2nd last question?  The user won't know the progress until the end where it won't serve much purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably display something like "**Step 1 of maximum 5**" or "**Step 1 of at most 5**", adjusting the total to be the maximum possible at each node in your workflow.

Comment: Perhaps displaying percentages instead of 1 of n is a better solution in this case.  I'm not too fond of using "at most" or "maximum".  I guess this begs the question, if the data is unknown and may mislead the user, why display it in the first place?

Comment: I agree that maybe the progress should not be shown as a part of a total at all, if the total is not known. My answer only applies if that decision is already made. That said, in a questionnaire with many questions I'd personally prefer a "maximum" value instead of nothing.